# Reading Excel, XML MAP element name using Apache POI

Tags: java, xml, excel, apache-poi

I have a business requirement in which I have been provided with excel document that has xml mapping in place (basically using excel menu option Developer-> Source and then selecting an xml file and mapping XML elements to the excel cells). For eg: Value in cell A2 is mapped to xml element "document_title", B2 is mapped to "document_number".

The requirement is to read the excel document programmatically and search for a list of XML elements and find the mapped cells and the contents of the cell. For eg: Search xml element "document_title" and find the cell to which this element is mapped to (in the example mentioned above, this is A2) and read the content of the cell.

I have tried using OPCP package and XSSFReader classes of apache POI and try to parse it using DOMParser but unable to achieve this.

Following is a trimmed version of source code, can someone please help me in the right direction.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println( "reading excel" );

    try {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open("D:\\test.xlsx");
        XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg ); 
        SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

        InputStream inp = r.getSheet("rId1"); 

        InputSource inpSource = new InputSource(inp);

        DOMParser parser = new DOMParser(); 
        parser.parse(inpSource); 

        Document doc = parser.getDocument(); 
        inp.close();  // dont know yet, how to read each element, and hence trying to write this to a file

        OutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("D:\\outtrId11.xml"); 
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer(); 
                                trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); 
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 

        //create string from xml tree 

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer); 
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); 
        trans.transform(source, result);            

    } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OpenXML4JException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please let me know in case of any queries/suggestions. Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of crawling through the internet, I found an example posted to workaround a bug in one of the POI class. I have tweaked the code from that example to my need and got exactly what was required.

So following code, in summary, reads an xlsx file, retrieves any relations (in this case, the relation I am interested is tableSingleCells as this contains the xml map data). The code then parses this document for all mapped XML elements and the associated cell reference.

Finally, I display the XML elements, the xpath and the cell value of the cell associated to these XML elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     System.out.println( "reading excel" );

     File file = new File("D:\\test.xlsx");
     // load an XLSX file with mapping informations

     XSSFWorkbook wb;
     wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getAbsolutePath());

        for( XSSFSheet sheet : wb ) {

            for( POIXMLDocumentPart doc : sheet.getRelations() ) {

                final PackagePart part = doc.getPackagePart();
                assert null!=part;

                if( part==null ) {
                    System.out.println("part of relation is null. Will be ignored!");
                    continue;
                }

                //System.out.println(String.format("contentType [%s]", part.getContentType()));

                if(part.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.tableSingleCells+xml"))
                {
                    System.out.println(String.format("contentType [%s]", part.getContentType()));

                    SingleXmlCellsDocument singleCellsXml = SingleXmlCellsDocument.Factory.parse( part.getInputStream() );
                    CTSingleXmlCells scs = singleCellsXml.getSingleXmlCells();

                    for( CTSingleXmlCell sc :  scs.getSingleXmlCellArray() ) {

                        //get R reference
                        final String ref = sc.getR();

                        //get cell reference
                        final CellReference cellRef = new CellReference( ref );
                        final CTXmlCellPr cellPr = sc.getXmlCellPr();

                        //get xml element reference
                        final CTXmlPr pr = cellPr.getXmlPr();

                        //get xpath reference
                        final String xpath = pr.getXpath();

                        //navigate to the cell by setting row and column
                        final int rowNum = cellRef.getRow();
                        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

                        final int colNum = cellRef.getCol();
                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell( colNum);


                        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

                        String cellStrValue="";

                        cellStrValue=formatter.formatCellValue(cell);


                        //System.out.println(xpathQuery);
                        final String xpathQuery = String.format("[Cell Reference: " + ref +  "] [Element Name: "+ cellPr.getUniqueName()  + "] [Cell Value: " + cellStrValue  + "] [Full xpath: " + xpath + "]" );
                        System.out.println(xpathQuery);


                    }

                }

            }

        }

        wb.close();

}
```

Hope this helps someone. Feel free to ask if there are any queries.

Thanks,

Comment: Please include the import. I can't understand where you are getting certaing Objects from!